# Words with meaning: someone who show/deal/focus in a particular area (not expert or enthusiast)

Tags: single-word-requests

I read a word this morning it starts with B or W or V. I don't remember it.

When I looked about it in Google in the morning they were no other synonyms below so now I am unable to track it down.

The meaning of the word is 'someone that shows interest/confined/deals with a particular area of interest'.

could you all come up with the words that pertain to the above, it is not a simple daily usage word though.

Comment: A _bpecialist_, a _waficionado_, or a _vexpert_?

Comment: no it only means that they deal in that particular area but not an expert in that.

Comment: **W**ell **v**ersed?

Comment: its really not that simple word

Comment: Is there a positive or negative connotation to the word?

Comment: It simply states that someone that cares, shows/deal interest in a particular area not an expert or enthusiast though.

Comment: It's probably too late, but did you look in your browser history?

Comment: they were already too many other words I searched, next day after I closed and reopened (although it restored where I left) the backward button is only showing words to certain limit and the rest are gone (from the word that I first typed to - some other words in middle, gone). Wish gmail was logged in so I can look into search history but I was only logged into twitter at that time.

Answer (score 2):

You might be looking for the word **aficionado** or **enthusiast**.

Both refer to a person who is interested and knowledgeable in "a particular area".

There's also **connoisseur**, but I don't think that meets the criteria in your question.

You may want to run these words through the thesaurus and see if you find the word that possibly starts with B, W or V.

Comment: thank you for you response

I am familiar with the above words but no. I guess, I read it in a article about noble price it is a very new word to me. I should have written it down

Comment: yes I went thru my excel sheet which I build that contain 5000 words A-Z. I couldn't find it cuz this is a new word

Comment: post any other hints you can think of that may narrow down the search

Comment: When I typed the word in Google it showed up as someone who is close or has particular interest in a area (not expert or very much interested in that). No other words or synonyms were given below. I though this word is cool I can use it in my motivation letter or elsewhere. It sounded like verbatim or something like that I just cannot recollect.

Answer (score 0):

The most common word for it is probably ***specialist***.

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/specialist

> 1. a person who devotes himself or herself to one subject or to one particular branch of a subject or pursuit.

Given the starting letters, perhaps ***buff***

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/buff

> 4. a devotee or well-informed student of some activity or subject

or ***votary***

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/votary

> 3. a person who is devoted or addicted to some subject or pursuit

Comment: No it is somehow related to sphere, field, area...

Comment: I disagree that the most common word would be _specialist_. I may be interested in reading, playing guitar, and the New York Rangers, but unless I'm a book critic, have a music degree, or work as an ice hockey talent scout, I'm an enthusiast at best. The word *specialist* conjures images of podiatrists, pediatricians, oncologists, and heart surgeons, not someone who "shows interest" in a particular area. I do like _votary_, though. That's a cool word that begins with _v_, and, FWIW, it has no synonyms listed in my thesaurus app.

Comment: Votary: monk nun religious service, but the word I have seen has nothing to do with these. It simply states that someone that shows/deal interest in a particular area not an expert or enthusiast though.